# Excluding Projects from a Build in TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teamcity

At work we've added SQL Database projects to our VS 2010 project as a way of keeping control of changes in stored procedures and schema changes. Unfortunately, it is now breaking the build on our TeamCity CI server.

Is there a way to tell TeamCity not to build these projects or will I have to accept defeat and install Visual Studio 2010 on the TeamCity CI server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Option 1

Make a copy of your current .sln and remove the SQL db projects; then point TeamCity at this sln instead.

### Option 2

Make a new Build Configuration (you have Debug, Release and you could add DebugCI as an example) and tick the projects you want compiled in this configuration. Then in the build step setup type DebugCI into the `Configuration` box: (is Debug in this screenshot but you get the idea)

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I'll give it a go and let you know what happens.

Comment: I'm replying to this rather late but this worked for me.